# hesitation about getaddrinfo() correct usage for both handling IPV4 and IPV6

Tags: c++, network-programming, ipv6, ipv4

I'm trying to write an IP Address class that both handles IPV6 and IPV4 addresses; to reach this purpose I'm using the sockadrr_storage data structure.
I've already written most of this class but now I've got some difficulties on creating an interface that uses in a correct and clever way the getaddrinfo() function.
I mean I want to create a constructor that could give and insert the right IP address in the sockadrr_storage data structure after having put a set of parameters.
Some examples:

- **ip_address ip_v4("127.0.0.1");** -> This will give a loopback address
- **ip_address ip_v6("::", 0 , AF_INET6 , SOCK_STREAM);** -> This will give a V6 link local
- **ip_address host_adr("www.google.it");** -> This will perform a dns lookup

To do this, this function has to make a call to getaddrrinfo() with the right parameters.
I have to handle those cases:

- **loopback V4 and V6**
- **wildcard V4 and V6**
- **numerical string V4 and V6**
- **hostname string V4 and V6**

Here there is the code I have written until now.

```
bool ip_address::parse_addr(std::string addr_ , std::string port_ , int ai_family , int ai_socktype)
{

  struct addrinfo hints , * host_info ;
  memset(&hints , 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));

  switch(ai_family)
  {
    case AF_INET:
      hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
      hints.ai_socktype = ai_socktype;
      break;

    case AF_INET6:
      hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;
      hints.ai_socktype = ai_socktype;
      break;
  }

  getaddrinfo(addr_.c_str(), port_.c_str(), &hints, &host_info);

  if(host_info->ai_family == AF_INET )
  {
    struct sockaddr_in adr;
    memset(&adr,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    adr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    size_ = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    address_.ss_family = AF_INET;
    ((struct sockaddr_in *)&address_)->sin_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in *) host_info->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
  }
  else if(host_info->ai_family == AF_INET6 )
  {
    struct sockaddr_in6 adr;
    memset(&adr,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
    adr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    size_ = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6);
    address_.ss_family = AF_INET6;
    ((struct sockaddr_in6 *)&address_)->sin6_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in6 *) host_info->ai_addr)->sin6_addr;
  }

  freeaddrinfo(host_info);


return false;
```

**parse_addr()** is the method that is called from the constructor of **ip_address** class.

At the moment this code only works for the IPV4. In fact as I add this call `ip_address ip_v6("::", 0 , AF_INET6 , SOCK_STREAM);`to the main() it gives **Segmentation fault**.

**Do you see anything wrong in this code?**

Then I have a more generic question: **could this be a clever solution to handle this problem? If you have any suggestions please let me know.**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are not showing the constructor code for ip_address. You can set hints.ai_socktype outside the switch (this is not an error though). The code is not checking return value of getaddrinfo, if it failed, host_info may have an invalid value. Where are you getting the segmentation fault? Where is address_ declared? (did you mean adr?)